# Integrate with Google button returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have a public market place app which we can install from the Chrome webstore . The "Integrate With Google" button is visible in the webstore.

However when we try to put the same button in our website using

<g:additnow applicationid="APP-ID"></g:additnow>

We get a 403 Forbidden error from apis.google.com/additnow/additnow.html.

I have verified that our app is public, app id is correct, even listed out website url in the clien id javascript origins.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/button#getting_started), after you publish your app to the store it may take a few days for the button to become active:

> Note: After your app is published on Google App Marketplace, it may take a number of days before the Integrate with Google button can successfully install your app. Make sure to try it on a local page and make sure that it is working before placing the button on a live website.

The 403 error message indicates that it isn't active yet. Please try again in a couple of days.