# Launch App is not shown after Integrate with Google button is pressed

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

For some reason after pressing "Integrate with Google" button on our site and agreeing with terms on provided on a separate window no confirmation modal popup appear where and admin can press Launch App.

Window example: http://www.apptivo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Launch-App.png

It happens for a for a week already.

Does someone know what is the reason for that?
Actually I need a way to launch Additional Settings URL.

Comment: This question may be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591706/integrate-with-google-button-returns-403-forbidden

Comment: It's an old application and worked till last week... BTW, I see such a behavior for all other Marketplace applications.